# Как скрыть другие открытые спойлеры при открывании спойлера

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Ребята, помогите отредактировать код. На странице есть категории партнёров, в которых есть имена партнёров. Все скрыто под спойлерами. По умолчанию открыт тот спойлер, в котором находится партнер по умолчанию. Вот мой сайт о котором я говорю: [Перейти на сайт](http://37.143.12.120/partners/)

А вот собственно код, который открывает спойлеры:

```
$(".panelHNavElement").click(function(){
        if ($(this).find("img.sparrow").attr("src") == "/images/arrow-u.svg") {
          $(this).find("img.sparrow").attr("src", "/images/arrow-d.svg");
        } else {
          $(this).find("img.sparrow").attr("src", "/images/arrow-u.svg");
        }

       $(this).parent().children("div.panelHNavElementSpoilerBody").slideToggle("normal");
      });
```

Необходимо изменить код так, что бы при нажатии на любой спойлер, который должен открыться, все открытые спойлеры закрывались. Потому что сейчас можно открыть неограниченное количество спойлеров, и в этом случае получается длинная газета на сайте:)

Comment: у вас там еще одна проблема, после второго клика на меню, оно не закрывается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В начале функции-обработчика:

```
$(".panelHNavElement").click(function(){
  $("div.panelHNavElementSpoilerBody").hide();
  ...
```

Comment: Супер. Спасибо! Система примет ваш ответ как правильный через 7 мин)